# Changing color of nav pills bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three navigation pills at the top for each section of my webpage.

[image]

When I scroll through the website, the pill will become active, and should display a white colored font (this is taken care of in Jquery, which is not my concern here).

Here's my CSS:

```
#home:hover, #resume:hover, #contact:hover,
#home:focus, #resume:focus, #contact:focus,
#home:active, #resume:active, #contact:active {
    background-color: #536872;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I've also added a `!important` at the end of the `background-color`, but the background still shows up as blue. My question is, how do I get rid of the blue background when the navigation pill is active?

EDIT: This is what I'm using in Jquery to removeClass/addClass when I'm scrolling. I've pinpointed my problem down to this, but don't know why it's causing the background color to be unchangeable.

script.js:

```
//Change active class when scrolling
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (position <= home.top - 80) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position >= home.top - 80) {
        $('.home-class').addClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > resume.top - 50) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').addClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (position > contact.top - 50) {
        $('.home-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.resume-class').removeClass('active');
        $('.contact-class').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: `! important` is used only to show that this is important property. do not change.

Comment: May I ask how is that relevant to the question? With or without, having `!important` doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @homeboy read your last lines in que. I was just clearing your doubt. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:active` is only invoked when the button or link is being clicked. It is not the same as the class `.active`

What you need to do is update the background colour on the `.active` class selector.

In bootstrap the css looks like this :

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a, 
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, 
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

Comment: I also have a `.active` in my CSS but still doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills your_nav_class">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.your_nav_class .active a,.your_nav_class .active a:hover,.your_nav_class .active a:focus {
    background-color: #536872;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**Demo Link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/Y36FV/225/

Comment: I am aware that the tags does not include Python. However, you be able to provide this solution in python as well for those users who are coding using Dash Bootstrap in Python.